# MIPS: Finding the kth largest integer

Tags: assembly, mips

This code has somehow got in a loop of taking infinite number of inputs.
I need to take some limited number of integers say `n = 10` and then take another input from keyboard say `k = 3`. And then I have to output the 3rd largest number out of those 10 numbers.

The prompts and outputs should be like this:

```
Enter count: 5
Enter integers: -5
3
12
8
2
Enter k: 2
kth largest is: 8
Enter count: 5
Enter integers: -5
3
12
8
2
Enter k: 6
Error
```

Code

```
    .data
    .align 2
    myarray: .space 160
    endline: .asciiz "\n"
    msg: .asciiz "Enter count(number of integers to be input): "
    msg2: .asciiz "Enter integers: "
    msg4: .asciiz "Enter k: "
    msg3: .asciiz "kth largest integer is: "
    msg5: .asciiz "Error"
    msg6: .asciiz "I will do something here"
.text
 main:  


    #show the the msg1
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,msg
    syscall

    #enter the number of integers(n)
    li $v0,5
    syscall
    move $t4,$v0 #value of (n)

    #take input of n numbers
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,msg2
    syscall

    j fun

temp:
    #take input of k
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,msg4
    syscall

    li $v0,5
    syscall
    move $t2,$v0 #value of k

    #if k>n error
    bgt $t2,$t4,showerror       

    #if k<=n do something
    ble $t2,$t4,func

    #end
    li $v0,10  
    syscall

    fun:

    addi $sp,$sp,-4
    #enter the numbers
    li $v0,5 
    syscall

    mul $t4,$t4,4

    beq $t0,$t4,exit #($t0=40 =>exit)

    sw $v0,myarray($t0)

    addi $t0,$t0,4
    addi $sp,$sp,4
    j fun

    exit:
    jr $ra

    showerror:
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,msg5 
    syscall

    func:
    li $v0,5
    la $a0,msg6
    syscall
```

Update: I updated the code as you mentioned to add jal but I had tried that previously with no luck.

Comment: `jr $ra` from something that you didn't use `jal` to jump to is typically a mistake.

Comment: previously I tried that doesn't work it is accepting infinite inputs also updates the code in the question please see

Comment: It should be easy for you to find the problem if you step through this in a debugger (hint: watch the value of `$t4`).